# How does posix_memalign differ from mmap

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, mmap, memory-alignment

How does [posix_memalign](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/posix_memalign.html) with alignment size of 4096 bytes differ from `mmap`? Does it internally use `mmap` or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`posix_memalign` is a higher-level API than `mmap`, designed to interoperate with `malloc`, `free` and `realloc`. `mmap` usage is more complicated because it offers more functionality than `posix_memalign` (mapping files into a process's address space). How it is implemented (in terms of `mmap` or otherwise) is left unspecified by the POSIX standard.

Use `posix_memalign` where you'd use `malloc` if you didn't have alignment restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

> How does posix_memalign with alignment size of 4096 bytes differ from mmap?

The obvious answer: posix_memalign cannot mmap arbitrary files by fd. :)

As for allocation behavior of posix_memalign vs. mmap(MAP_ANOYMOUS): I see no requirement that posix_memalign(size) has to use mmap. It could as well share the sbrk mechanism with/from malloc and return you a properly-aligned pointer to part of the brk area.

Answer (score 1):

Where `mmap` is available, `posix_memalign` is usually implemented using `mmap`. The main difference is that `posix_memalign` is in stdlib.h, where as `mmap` is a system call which might not be available and have different semantics on different platforms.

Comment: `mmap` is specified by POSIX, so it should have the same semantics on any conforming platform.

Comment: @larsmans: while `mmap` is specified by X/Open (POSIX) the `MAP_ANON` flag / behaviour (to use `mmap` for allocating memory) and/or the use of `-1` as filedescriptor is _not_ part of the portable specification. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html for what's (not) in the standard for `mmap`.

Answer (score 1):

From the standards (POSIX) point of view, [`posix_memalign()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html) doesn’t really have any connection to [`mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html):

> #### `posix_memalign` - aligned memory allocation
>
> The `posix_memalign()` function shall allocate size bytes aligned on a
> boundary specified by alignment, and shall return a pointer to the
> allocated memory in `memptr`.

> #### `mmap` - map pages of memory
>
> The `mmap()` function shall establish a mapping between an address space
> of a process and a memory object.
>
> The `mmap()` function shall be supported for the following memory
> objects:
>
> - Regular files
> - [[SHM]](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#SHM) > Shared memory objects <
> - [[TYM]](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#TYM) > Typed memory objects <
>
> Support for any other type of file is unspecified.

In particular, POSIX does not specify the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag that can be used (e. g. on Linux) to use `mmap()` to allocate memory without a corresponding file. So, a priori, the two functions perform unrelated tasks: `posix_memalign()` allocates dynamic memory (which POSIX `mmap()` cannot do), while `mmap()` maps files into the process address space (which `posix_memalign()` cannot do, as stated in [jørgensen’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455840)).

When talking about systems which support `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, such as Linux (which was tagged in the question), `mmap()` gains a capability similar to `posix_memalign()`, although `mmap()` will return a pointer aligned to the system page size, while `posix_memalign()` can be used to obtain memory with a different alignment as well.

Finally, [memory allocated with `posix_memalign()` is freed using `free()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html), while [`mmap()` is cleaned up using `munmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/munmap.html).

Comment: Without MAP_ANONYMOUS, you can actually open `/dev/zero` and mmap it with MAP_PRIVATE to get effectively anonymous memory.  I think I've heard of that being actually done on some older Unixes 
as a way to avoid using brk for everything.

Comment: @PeterCordes I’ve seen that technique on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap#Example_of_usage_under_the_C_programming_language), but I don’t think it’s standardized anywhere or guaranteed to work. At least (according to the Wikipedia page) it doesn’t seem to work on Mac OS X/macOS.

Comment: Modern OSes that came long after widespread support for MAP_ANONYMOUS don't really need to support mmap of /dev/zero.  Fair point that portable code shouldn't use it (and hopefully doesn't), but the internal implementation of `malloc` for a *specific* OS's libc certainly could, for large allocations.  Very few programs try to reimplement malloc, and malloc libraries would use #ifdef to choose that nasty fallback (which would need to manage an fd for it) only on OSes where it works and MAP_ANONYMOUS isn't available.